# Отображение json в idea

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

Как можно более наглядно отобразить json в idea использую org json, json.toString() он отображает не понять много много длинных строк

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для форматирования JSON строки можете использовать или [данный сайт](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/), или [данный плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3964?pr=idea) (если форматирование необходимо прямо в IDEA).